# Pygame attribute, init()

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3

I'm trying to use Pygame with Python 3.3 on my windows 8 laptop. Pygame installed fine and when I `import pygame` it imports fine as well. Although when I try to execute this small code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

size=[700,500]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\documents\python\pygame_example.py", line 3, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

I used `pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_56e0eadfc267.win32-py3.3` to install Pygame. Pygame is installed in this location 'C:\PythonX' and Python 3.3 is installed in this location 'C:\Python33'. I have looked at other people having the same or similar problem and it doesn't seem to solve the error. Have I done anything wrong when installing Pygame? Or does it not support windows 8?

Comment: What does `import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)` print?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(pygame.__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__' @MartijnPieters

Comment: Interesting. No idea what you imported there, but I am trying to figure out if that is actually the `pygame` module or something else. It is certainly possible that the 'real' `pygame` module has no `.__file__` attribute, but it *is* surprising. Does `print(pygame)` give any detail?

Comment: Also, I want you to add the `print()` statements to your script, not run them in a Python shell please.

Comment: When I printed `print(pygame.__file__)` in my script I still got the same error as before and when I printed `print(game)` in my script I got this: `<module 'pygame' (namespace)>`. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 13):

After
import pygame
pygame.init()

I got this error message and programm didnt work:
" AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' "

because i named the file "pygame.py"...

When i chaned filename to "pygametest.py" everything worked.

Naming the filename exactly like the modulename seems to confuse python...

Answer (score 8):

You have a *directory* named `pygame` in your path somewhere.

```
$ mkdir pygame  # empty directory
$ python3.3
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame
<module 'pygame' (namespace)>
>>> pygame.__path__
_NamespacePath(['./pygame'])
```

Remove or rename this directory, it is masking the actual pygame package.

If you use `print(pygame.__path__)` it'll tell you where the directory was found; in the above example it was found relative to the current directory (`./`).

Comment: Nice detective work. Isn't this supposed to happen only with directories containing `__init__.py`?

Comment: @interjay: No, not in Python 3, which added namespace support (what `setuptools` does with special `__init__.py` files).

Comment: @interjay: see http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages

Comment: I see. I guess the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/modules.html) is outdated then because it says: "The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path."

Comment: @interjay: these are not packages. These are namespaces. :-P

Comment: @interjay: but if you feel that the tutorial is now no longer correct, do feel free to file a bug with the Python project.

Comment: btw: You can get the same error if you put your code in file `pygame.py`

Comment: @furas: but then `import pygame; print(pygame.__file__)` prints a filename for that module or package.

Answer (score 1):

I also named my ***app pygame.py*** and i had the same issue but when i changed it, it worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Try to place the pygame module in `.\PythonX\Lib\site-packages\`

I use pip to install all modules I need.

Have you downloaded pygame and manually placed it in the `PythonX` folder ? Maybe the error comes from that.