# Pygame import error

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am using pygame 1.9.2pre with python3. When I run idle3 and type

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.init()
```

this works perfectly however when I write these two lines in a .py file and then run it in idle3 (by opening it and hitting F5) I get this messege

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nabeel/Devalopment/Python/pygame.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/home/nabeel/Devalopment/Python/pygame.py", line 9, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

Comment: Have you tried if you have the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912810/pygame-attribute-init ?

Comment: Name your file something different from `pygame.py`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your file something different from `pygame.py` otherwise your program will default to importing your own file and obviously that is not what you want since you want the other module.

You can use `print(pygame.__path__)` to check where it is that you are actually getting your `pygame module` from and in your case it would point to the directory you are currently in.

Comment: @nabeel, No problem! Happy pygaming!