# Pygame In PyCharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I can not import Pygame in pycharm. I’ve looked at videos and other posts. I have it installed, both on the PyCharm interpreter and on my system. I get an error that says no module named Pygame, module Pygame does not have an init attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pygame attribute, init()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912810/pygame-attribute-init)

Comment: @blackbrandt thank you. This could be the issue. The file is named “Pygame”. Would this affect it even though the first letter is uppercase?

Comment: Yes, that will make the import command look in the wrong place for pygame, and so you will get your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to File > Settings > Double Click on Project: (Your project name) > Project Interpreter > The + Button on the right side of the window. Also make sure you typed  `import pygame` on the first line of the program.